# Node js jwt - Verify middleware not working for my secured routes

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jwt

I'm a little back end developer for the node js. Currently, I'm creating an application to increase my skill level with node js. So I thought i'd try to learn JSON webtoken(jwt) for the user authentication part. I am using [this link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/authenticate-a-node-js-api-with-json-web-tokens) to get an idea of how it works. But now I have a problem that I must change and then fix that differs from the tutorial. The middleware that the tutorial gives you is not working for the secured routes. So let me describe what happens when my code runs.  If we didn't provide any token to any route that the middleware checks then the router works as we expect it to without returning any errors from the middleware. So please let me know a solution to fix this in the easiest possible way. Thank you.

secured routes file for api

```
//Node js libraries
const express       =           require('express');
const router        =           express.Router();
const app           =           express();
const jwt           =           require('jsonwebtoken');

//Static files
const Users         =           require('../models/users');

app.set('superSecret', 'thisissecretkeyforapi');

//Routes here
router.post('/', function(req, res){
    if(req.body.username == '' || req.body.password == '') {
        res.send('Fields must be required');
    }
    else {
        Users
        .findOne({
            username: req.body.username
        },
        function(err, user){
            if(!user){
                res.send('No user found');
            }
            else {
                if(user.password != req.body.password) {
                    res.send('Wrong password');
                }
                else {
                    var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
                        expiresIn: 60*15
                    });
                    res.send({
                        message: "Token here",
                        token: token
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    }
})

router.get('/profile', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.decoded);
    res.send('profile here');
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js file for all middlewares

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://cordy:lolla123@ds042459.mlab.com:42459/musiclk', {
    useMongoClient: true
});

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set('superSecret', 'thisissecretkeyforapi');

app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('./controllers/index')(app);

app.set('superSecret', 'thisissecretkeyforapi');

admin_routes = require('./controllers/admin_routes');

admin_routes.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
    var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    // decode token
    if (token) {
        // verifies secret and checks exp
        jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded) {      
            if (err) {
                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'Failed to authenticate token. The token is expired' });    
            }
            else {
                // if everything is good, save to request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;    
                next();
            }
        });
    } else {
        // if there is no to
        // return an error
        return res.status(403).send({ 
            success: false, 
            message: 'No token provided.' 
        });
    }
});

app.use('/admin', admin_routes);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 1337, function(){
    console.log("Now listening for the requests");
});
```

There is all of my code.

Comment: show us your code, because the tutorials code is right, it should work and show error in response if implemented right.

Comment: ok wait i'll edit the post withing my code

Comment: I am sure you are not mistaking in testing, but just to get on the same page; you are testing with following routes, `POST /admin` or `GET /admin/profile`. right?

Comment: When user entered the currect username and password, that POST routes generates the token. So when i use this token to GET routes req.decoded object shown me as undefined. So i think that means the middleware is mpt setup properly???

Comment: and i'm testing with GET /admin/profile route